# syncing a personal calendar with sharepoint calendars in 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, calendar

Guys i know you cant sync your personal calendar with your team sharepoint calendars in 2010 but i was wondering whether this is now possible in 2013 using exchange 2013.

Currently we just send an email to the sharepoint calendar when booking holidays and meetings but its not ideal and we were hoping that this feature is now available in 2013.

Ive done a search but cant find any information on it.  If this is not possible OOTB is there a 3rd party solution or an outlook workaround available.  If you know of any 3rd party tools can you please specify the name so i can have a look into it

Answer (score 1):

In 2013 as in 2010 you can sync Calendars with the Calendar Overlay option. Add a new Calendar and instead of SharePoint calendar choose Exchange and fill in your exchange web services an OWA addresses

[image]

Tell me if you need further information

**EDITED**

Overlay calendars in outlook

[image]

After clicking the arrow

[image]

Comment: thanks but im not sure i understand.  What we want is for any sharepoint calendars you have synced to update when you create an appointment in your personal calendar.

Comment: I haven't tested with Exchange 2013. But a Workaround if I understood your issue is to combine the calendars into a single view, click the arrow on the tab of SharePoint calendar. See my update (image)

Comment: They have this feature 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-foundation-help/overlay-a-sharepoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-exchange-or-sharepoint-HA101777171.aspx. But it doesn't work